# Show specific value in Textbox according to combobox selected value in python

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter, textbox

How can I show the combobox value in my textbox widget?

Here is my coding, it said I need to put the event argument, so what event argument should I put in order to show my combobox value in my textbox widget?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
class Application:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.value_of_combo='A'
        self.combo()
        self.textArea()

    def textArea(self,event):
        self.value_of_combo = self.box.get()
        print(self.value_of_combo)
        thistextArea=Text(self.parent,height=50,wideth=50)
        thistextArea.grid(column=0,row=1)

    def combo(self):
        self.box_value = StringVar()
        self.box = ttk.Combobox(self.parent, textvariable=self.box_value,values=('A', 'B', 'C'),state='readonly')
        self.box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',self.textArea)
        self.box.current(0)
        self.box.grid(column=0, row=0)

root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `thistextArea.insert()` to insert text into the textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about  which event argument to pass to `textArea`() method: you rather have to fix the following errors:

1. First of all, remove the call to `textArea()` inside `__init__()`, it is rather `combo()` that needs it.
2. Inside `textArea()` you are creating a new Text widget each time the callback `combo()` is called. So you need to move those 2 lines that create and position the Text widget from `textArea()` to `combo()` instead.
3. Once this is fixed, the algorithm is simple: when selecting a value from the Combobox widget you need to check if the Text widget is empty: if so, insert the value directly, if not delete the existing text before insertion.

**Program:**

Here is the solution with the related errors fixed:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
class Application:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.value_of_combo='A'
        self.combo()
        #self.textArea() <-- This has nothing to do here, remove it

    def textArea(self, e):
        self.value_of_combo = self.box.get()
        print(self.value_of_combo)
        # Get the content of the Text widget
        r=self.thistextArea.get('1.0','1.end')
        # If it is empty then insert the selected value directly
        if not r:
           self.thistextArea.insert(INSERT, self.value_of_combo) 
        # If not empty then delete existing text and insert the selected value
        else: 
           self.thistextArea.delete('1.0','1.end')               
           self.thistextArea.insert(END, self.value_of_combo)


    def combo(self):
        self.box_value = StringVar()        
        self.box = ttk.Combobox(self.parent, textvariable=self.box_value,values=('A', 'B', 'C'),state='readonly')
        self.box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',self.textArea)
        self.box.current(0)
        self.box.grid(column=0, row=0)        
        self.thistextArea=Text(self.parent,height=50,width=50)
        self.thistextArea.grid(column=0,row=1)

root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```